# POSTing into Web API from C# (MVC)

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post

What is the equivalent in `C#(from the controller(MVC))`  for `POSTing value into a Web API method using a standard jQuery $.post`,

I have it working using a standard jQuery $.post, like this:

```
  $.post('/api/reports', { AgentId: AgentId, ReportName: ReportName, Params: Params, StatsEmailedId: StatsEmailedId, HeaderName: HeaderName,
        RankBy: RankBy, SoldCountsInclude: SoldCountsInclude, SortBy: SortBy, IncludeCo: IncludeCo, DisplayTop: DisplayTop, UserOffice: UserOffice
    },
function (data) { ....
      }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean you want to call one of your own WebAPI methods from your controller?

Comment: Thats right. The Webapi is in a separate project from the project I want to call it from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain I understand fully the question. If you are meaning how to post to a controller from jquery (rather than api), then it's a simple change along the lines of:

```
  $.post('@Url.Action("actioname","controller")', { AgentId: AgentId, ReportName: ReportName, Params: Params, StatsEmailedId: StatsEmailedId, HeaderName: HeaderName,
        RankBy: RankBy, SoldCountsInclude: SoldCountsInclude, SortBy: SortBy, IncludeCo: IncludeCo, DisplayTop: DisplayTop, UserOffice: UserOffice
    },
function (data) { ....
      }
});
```

If calling an internal method inside a controller, then you'd just call it as if invoking another method call inside the controller.

A further point raised is that you may have your js inside its own file, in which case, you can't use the `@Url.Action()` stuff. In this case, I'd advise using the jquery data-attributes and placing the target URL onto one of your key dom elements and then targetting that from your js using the .data('your-attr') from the source file. Works very well and is definitely my recommendation.

**[edit]** - althought the question is def related to `WebClient`, i think it's worth demonstrating what I mean by using the data-attributes for the external js implementation:

```
//the cshtml code
<button id="myUpdateButton" data-target-url="@Url.Action("youraction", "controller")">

//the js code (assumes click on myUpdateButton)
var targetUrl = $(this).data('target-url');
// then use targetUrl in place of the 1st param in the `$.post` method.
```

Anyway, just me being ott :-)

Comment: Note, the Url.Action technique only works if your javascript is not in a .js file (it needs to be in a .cshtml file).

Comment: I want to post to a Web API from MVC controller (c#).

Comment: ok, in that case, and assuming a differtent project, just treat as if it's an extermnal resource and use the WebClient lib

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call an WebApi method in a different project/somewhere else from your controller, I would use the WebClient. You can use this to make any web call from C#. Check out specifically its UploadData method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested you could use the WebClient class. There are a couple of alternatives you could also try. Take a look at HttpClient and RestSharp, both available via nuget. I've personally used RestSharp with a number of 3rd party APIs as well as my own APIs to great effect.